# python bug with __le__, __ge__?

Tags: python

Is it me or python that is confused with the following code ?  I would expect `__le__` to be called by `a <= ab`, not `__ge__`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

class B(object):
    def __ge__(self, other):
        print("__ge__ unexpectedly called")

class A(object):
    def __le__(self, other):
        print("__le__ called")

class AB(A, B):
    pass

a = A()
ab = AB()

a <= ab # --> __ge__ unexpectedly called
ab <= a # --> __le__ called
```

I get the same behavior with python 2.7, 3.2 and pypy 1.9.

What can I do to get `__le__` called instead of `__ge__` ??

Comment: Why do you have all that complicated stuff with the `make` function, when you could just do `a = A()` and `ab = AB()` and get the same objects? (I can see why it might be useful in your real program, but it doesn't affect this example at all, and it will probably throw off some people who want to investigate and hopefully answer.)

Comment: Indeed, the simplified version you propose also have the same behavior. Now corrected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is that they wanted to allow `AB` to override the behavior from `A`. Python can't call `AB.__lt__(a, ab)`, because `a` may not be a valid `self` for an `AB` method, so instead, it calls `AB.__gt__(ab, a)`, which is valid.

The long answer is a bit more complicated.

According to the docs for [rich comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection.

In other words, `x <= y` will call `y.__ge__(x)` in exactly the same cases where `x+y` would call `y.__radd__(x)`. To compare:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         print('X.add')
>>> class Y(object):
...     def __radd__(self, other):
...         print('Y.radd')
>>> class XY(X, Y):
...     pass
>>> x, xy = X(), XY()
>>> x + xy
Y.radd
```

According to the docs for [reflected operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations… with reflected (swapped) operands. These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types…
>
> **Note**: If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.

So, because `XY` is a subclass of `X`, `XY.__radd__` gets preference over `X.__add__`. And, likewise, because `AB` is a subclass of `A`, `AB.__ge__` gets preference over `A.__le__`.

This probably should be documented better. To figure it out, you have to ignore the parenthetical "to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does", guess that you need to look up the normal swapped operators (there's no link, or even mention, here), then ignore the wording that says "These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation", and see the "Note", which contradicts what came above… Also notice that the docs explicitly say, "There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators", only a paragraph before describing the swapped cases, which imply exactly such relationships…

Finally, this case seems odd, because `AB`, rather than overriding `__ge__` itself, just inherited it from `B`, which knows nothing about `A` and is unrelated to it. Presumably `B` didn't intend to have its subclasses override `A`'s behavior. But if `B` were meant to be used as a mixin for `A`-derived classes, maybe it *would* intend exactly such an override. And at any rate, the rule is probably already complicated enough without getting into where each method came from in the MRO. Whatever the reasoning, where the `__ge__` comes from is irrelevant; if it's there on the subclass, it gets called.

For your added final, question, "What can I do to get `__le__` called instead of `__ge__` ??"… well, you really can't, any more than you can get `X.__add__` called instead of `XY.__radd__`. Of course you can always implement an `AB.__ge__` (or `XY.__radd__`) that calls `A.__le__` (or `X.__add__`), but it's presumably easier to just implement `AB.__ge__` in such a way that it works with an `A` as its other argument in the first place. Alternatively, you could remove the inheritance and find some other way to model whatever you were modeling that way. Or you could explicitly call `a.__le__(ab)` instead of `a<=ab`. But otherwise, if you designed your classes in a way that takes advantage of the "no implied relationships" to do something weird, you were misled by the docs, and will have to redesign them somehow.

Comment: I know that, but why would it call `__ge__` when `__le__` is available ??

Comment: Because "the right operand's type is a subclass of the left operand's type and that subclass provides the reflected method", which "allows subclasses to override their ancestors' operations". (If you're asking why it should matter given that `AB` inherited `__ge__` from `B` rather than defining it directly, that isn't taken into account by the rule. Probably because things are already complicated enough without adding that to the mix.)

Comment: @abarnert mentioned in his answer (+1, BTW) that it's to give the more derived class precedence, so as to allow it to override behavior.

Comment: @jimhark: Thanks for pointing out how important that is; I moved it from deep in the text near the bottom to up near the top.

Comment: And what about "ab>=a"?  Does python think ab.__ge__(ab, a) is better than a.__le__(a, ab), just because ab inherits the type of a?

Comment: @billybob: No it won't, it'll call `ab.__ge__(a)`, just as you'd expect; no swapping. (Also, `a<=ab` is not calling the incorrect method, it's calling the method it's supposed to call. It's just that the documentation is confusing, so you had no idea it was supposed to work that way.) If you meant `a>=ab` rather than `ab>=a`, that's actually calling `ab.__le__(a)`, which just happens to be inherited from `A` in this case, so that's the same as the original case, slightly disguised.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I now have a workaround : create another (empty) subclass of A, called AA, and use aa <= ab (instead of a <= ab).

Comment: @billybob: For the new version: Well, almost. For `a<=ab`, Python thinks `ab.__ge__(a)` is better than `a.__le__(ab)` because `type(ab)` is a subclass of `type(a)`. But for `ab>=a`, it's because `type(a)` is not a subclass of `type(ab)`. (You can see the distinction if you use completely unrelated types: `a<=b` uses `a.__le__(b)`, `b>=a` uses `b.__ge__(a)`, because in both cases, the right operand is not a subclass instance, and therefore there's no swap.

Comment: @user474491: Clever. Although I'm not sure why you want or need to do that. (Are you by any chance misusing `<=` as something other than a comparison to do some kind of Haskell-y thing, or do you just have objects where `<=` and `>=` are not mirror images of each other or something?)

Comment: Yes, I need the semantics of `__le__` and `__ge__` to be different.  It's for a logic programming package called [pyDatalog](https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/).

Comment: @user474491: Ah, so Prolog-y, not Haskell-y. I'm guessing `<=` defines relations, and `>=` extracts bound variables values, or something else that's obviously not just the reverse…

Comment: Yes.  "<=" means "if", and ">=" extracts bound variables values.  I could have avoided the problem by using ">" instead of ">=", but it's too late now.