# python : recursion loop in rich comparison operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I did not understand where is the logic in my bug, so I managed to find a minimal example. I defined one class `t`, and said that something happens when you use the <= operator and that a>=b must compute b<=a.
It works fine

Then I derived a subclass `u` from `t`.
When I compare two values, if they are both from `t` or both from `u` it works as expected, but if one is from class `u` and another from class `t` it fails. **Why** ??

```
class t :
    def __le__(self,other) : return True
    def __ge__(self,other) : return(other<=self)
class u(t) :
    pass

a=t()
b=u()
#works
a<=a
a>=a
b<=b
b>=b
#works
a>=b
b<=a
#doesn't work RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
a<=b
b>=a
```

EDIT : There is no problem in python 2.x (from tobias_k), but I want to use python 3.3 at least

Comment: which class is a and b?

Comment: @akaRem sorry, I added the definition of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Just FYI, in Python 2.x it 'works' as expected (returns true all the time).

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, I edited my question to include your remark.

Comment: The problems seems to be with comparator substitution, as the call to `return(other<=self)` seems to check `self >= other` instead, leading to infinite recursion... however, I do not know *why* it does so, and why only in those last two cases...

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, I agree with you but I did not find any explanation in the documentation to explain such a weird behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `a <= b` and `b` is an instance of a subclass of `a`'s class, Python will first call `b.__ge__('a')` (and then try other methods if this call returns `NotImplemented`)

Here is how to implement it without infinite recursion:

```
>>> class t:
...     def __le__(self, other):
...         return True
...     def __ge__(self, other):
...         return NotImplemented
... 
>>> class u(t):
...     pass
...
```

Comment: Is it a documented feature ?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen that in the doc, but I can't find where

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799386/python-bug-with-le-ge for a similar question and answer.  The documentation seems to be a combination of http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types (for subclass overriding and using NotImplemented as @ValentinLorentz suggested), and http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization for `"__le__"` and `"__ge__"` are each other's reflection. It seems like one has to piece the specification together oneself from these two sections.

Comment: @RoryYorke Thanks for the links, especially the SE question

Comment: @ValentinLorentz This is documented into http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__ where it is specified the order between reflected method and subclass method in the **Note : ...**