# Why are (lt, gt) and (le, ge) reflections instead of (lt, ge) and (le, gt)?

Tags: python

In [Basic customisation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customization), the python docs state about comparison methods:

> [no swapped-argument versions of these methods]; 
>   rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection.

I'd be less surprised by `__lt__()` and `__ge__()` being each other’s reflection(, as well as `__le__()` and `__gt__()`).

While the docs also state:

> … no other implied relationships among the comparison operators, for example, the truth of `(x<y or x==y)` does not imply `x<=y`,

what, if anything, is *the* or would be a rationale for the reflection relations chosen?

Comment: related: `@functools.total_ordering`, [python bug with __le__, __ge__?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13799386/3789665).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `a < b` and `b > a` are equivalent, as are `a <= b` and `b >= a`.

Comment: I seem to have misread _reflection_ for (logical) _complement_.

Answer (score 4):

Reflection means swapping the operands, not applying "not" to the operator.

```
__lt__(a,b)
    # if we don't know what to do, call
    return __gt__(b,a)
```

You were thinking the following

```
__lt__(a,b)
    # if we don't know what to do 
    return not __ge__(a,b)
```

But that's not what reflection means.